# is Redis stable on Windows?

Tags: redis

This afternoon, I used python script to test the performance of Redis on Windows. 
It worked normally when the number of threads was only 10, but some exceptions occured when the number of threads reached 100.

**Exception message:**

> 3 [main] redis-server 1448
>   _cygtls::handle_exceptions: Exception: STATUS_A CCESS_VIOLATION  1394 [main]
>   redis-server 1448 open_stackdumpfile:
>   Dumping stack trace to redi
>   s-server.exe.stackdump

Is Redis stable on Windows?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Redis is not officially supported on Windows. Some unofficial ports exist (such as the one you're using), but I believe stability is not guaranteed for these ports.

Comment: UPDATE: Please now see [**this post from Microsoft**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/interoperability/archive/2012/04/26/here-s-to-the-first-release-from-ms-open-tech-redis-on-windows.aspx) about MS Open Tech: [**Redis on Windows**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/interoperability/archive/2012/04/26/here-s-to-the-first-release-from-ms-open-tech-redis-on-windows.aspx)

Comment: MSOpenTech's is by far the most current port, years ahead of all others at this point, and as noted they are declaring it stable. See [my answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20200022/62600) for detailed steps on how to get it up and running - it's not particularly straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

Redis prime dev Salvatore Sanfilippo ('antirez'), [December 2011](http://antirez.com/post/redis-win32-msft-patch.html):

> I don't think Redis running under win32 is a very important feature. It is cool to have a win32 port that can be used for testing, as we had before, and as we have in a different implementation thanks to the Microsoft patch, so developers using Windows can easily test Redis and develop their projects. But what is the point in providing a production quality win32 port?

Regardless, parties within Microsoft are still [improving the Windows build](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/interoperability/archive/2012/04/26/here-s-to-the-first-release-from-ms-open-tech-redis-on-windows.aspx)

> Here’s to the first release from MS Open Tech: Redis on Windows
>
> Claudio Caldato 26 Apr 2012 12:01 PM 8
>
> We consider this not to be production ready code, but a solid code base to be shared with the community to solicit feedback: as such, while we pursue stabilization, we are keeping the older version as default/stable on the GitHub repository. To try out the new code, please go to the bksavecow branch.

Answer (score 1):

The [Redis download page](http://redis.io/download) now says "The Redis project does not directly support win32/win64, however we look at interest to projects trying to make a win32/win64 port that is separated from the main project...Currently both ports are not production quality but can be used for development purposes..."

Answer (score 1):

We maintain a stable and production ready Windows port (native!) of Redis.
The Developer Edition is free.
Check out Memurai.

Answer (score 0):

see:

[Redis on Windows stable and reliable](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/interoperability/archive/2013/04/22/redis-on-windows-stable-and-reliable.aspx)

I use it in my projects till last month and didn't experience any problems yet.