# How do I run Redis on Windows?

Tags: windows, redis

How do I run Redis on Windows? The Redis download page just seems to offer *nix options.

Can I run Redis natively on Windows?

Comment: Keep in mind that the most upvoted answer links to outdated repo with very old version of redis. If you need much newer version check my answer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19579610/1090562)

Comment: MSOpenTech [just announced](http://msopentech.com/blog/2014/03/24/updates-released-redis-windows) a production-ready build of Redis 2.8.4. It looks like [my instructions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20200022/62600) for gathering up all the bits are still relevant though.

Comment: for local development setup - http://geekindulgence.com/install-redis-as-a-windows-service-using-chocolatey/

Comment: I recommend using Docker on Windows with redis. few repos:
- the official redis repo: https://hub.docker.com/_/redis/ 
- the redis-enterprise repo (clustered redis running Redis Cloud by Redis Labs): https://hub.docker.com/r/redislabs/redis/

Comment: Pay attention to the **DATES** of the answers (and comments), which is more important than upvotes for this particular question. **MOST** answers (including mine) are now outdated. Microsoft's native port appears to be discontinued. If you have the latest Windows 10, running Redis on Ubuntu on Windows _appears_ to be quite possibly the best option. See [here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/redis-windows).

Comment: It looks like the MSFT port hasn't been updated since 2016.

Comment: Most answers are outdated and point to projects that are now abandoned. The MSOpenTech port was discontinued in 2016. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56140543/9540438)  for a solution that is up-to-date with the latest Redis (Redis 5, at the time of this writing).

Comment: I suggest using WSL for windows, https://redislabs.com/blog/redis-on-windows-10/

Comment: all these versions are outdated where can  found 6.0 version for windows. And why is they so difficult to find even when the Redis is used in almost all big projects?

Comment: # Redis Installation Link for Windows

https://github.com/tporadowski/redis/releases

Comment: you can use it compiled in cygwin see this instructions:
https://github.com/meiry/redis5_compiled_for_windows10

Answer (score 519):

Historically, Microsoft had a [Windows port of redis](https://github.com/microsoftarchive/redis/releases/latest), which was released as [Redis-64](https://www.nuget.org/packages/redis-64/), which offers a full distribution of redis for Windows.

The Microsoft port *is now deprecated*, but some alternatives have sprung up to fill that void:

- [Memurai](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MemuraiDeveloper/) is the alternative officially recommended on the Redis-64 deprecation page; it is a commercial offering with free developer tier, maintained by Janea Systems
- [redis-windows](https://github.com/zkteco-home/redis-windows) is another unofficial port, which also exists

---

This release includes the `redis-server.exe` (`memurai.exe` on Memurai) application that runs a Redis instance as a service on your windows machine, as well as `redis-cli.exe` (`memurai-cli.exe` on Memurai) which you can use to interact with any Redis instance.

The [RGL repository](https://github.com/rgl/redis) has historically been listed as an alternative Windows port for Redis, but this repository has not been maintained for some time and implements an older version of Redis than the Microsoft port.

Comment: Wasn't one click for me.  I've run the executable and still not sure how to get it to run

Comment: After running the installer, I had to manually put a redis.conf file in c:\Program Files\Redis, as described in the readme. I just copied c:\program files\Redis\conf\redis-dist.conf. Then I could start the service from the services control panel (or 'net start redis' from a command line)

Comment: I had to edit the service and change the account to "local system", otherwise the service would not start. I did not have to copy any config files.

Comment: To get most recent variant of this nice solution that still works on Windows Server 2003 you should:
1. Install as is + tune permissions if you set another user to run service with
2. Change exe files to ones w version 2.6.12 from Todd's solution (see next)
3. Remove strings in \conf\redis.conf from ###### VIRTUAL MEMORY ####
to the end

Comment: These versions are out of date years ago. The current recommendation is to use WSL.

Answer (score 327):

### Update

If you have `Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)`, natively on Windows 10 and Windows Server 2019 you can do it per
[Ogglas answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58853971/3011380)

Or follow these instructions to run a Redis database on Microsoft Windows

- 1. Turn on Windows Subsystem for Linux

  In Windows 10, Microsoft replaced Command Prompt with PowerShell as the default shell. Open PowerShell as Administrator and run this command to enable Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL):

  ```
  Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux
  ```

  Reboot Windows after making the change — note that you only need to do this once.
- 2. Launch Microsoft Windows Store

  ```
  start ms-windows-store:
  ```

  Then search for `Ubuntu`, or your preferred distribution of Linux, and download the latest version.
- 3. Install Redis server

  Installing Redis is simple and straightforward. The following example works with Ubuntu (you'll need to wait for initialization and create a login upon first use):

  ```
  sudo apt-add-repository ppa:redislabs/redis
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get upgrade
  sudo apt-get install redis-server
  ```

  Please note that the `sudo` command might or mightn't be required based on the user configuration of your system.
- 4. Restart the Redis server

  Restart the Redis server as follows:

  ```
  sudo service redis-server restart
  ```
- 5. Verify if your Redis server is running

  Use the redis-cli command to test connectivity to the Redis database.

  ```
  $ redis-cli
  127.0.0.1:6379> set user:1 "Ben"
  127.0.0.1:6379> get user:1
  "Ben"
  ```

  Please note: By default, Redis has 0-15 indexes for databases, you can change that number of databases NUMBER in `redis.conf`.
- 6. Stop the Redis Server

  ```
  sudo service redis-server stop
  ```

Source :[How to Install Redis on Windows](https://developer.redis.com/create/windows/)

---

I found one more simple way to install `Redis` under Windows

Download the latest `Redis` `.msi` file from

https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis/releases

after installation. The Redis service is installed, and we can operate it from `Service manager`

[image]

Comment: Yep, best solution even though I upvoted a solution above. This one does not require to start redis-server.exe to use it.

Comment: looks like work stopped at 3.2 pre-release but redis is now on 4.0

Comment: The most  simple way to get an instance of redise under the windows.

Comment: I got `The operation could not be completed`

Comment: The versions in https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis/releases are outdated. Current recommendation is to use WSL.

Comment: Here is the official blog with this solution: https://redislabs.com/blog/redis-on-windows-10/

Comment: I have it running and working with a program, but how do I access the webpage,  I tried navigating to localhost:6379 but nothings there

Answer (score 173):

**If you want to install MSOpenTech's latest port of Redis, on a Windows server, watched over by a Windows Service, without having to build anything yourself, read on.**

[MSOpenTech's](https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis) seems to be the only port that is actively trying to keep up with the latest and greatest Redis. They claim it is [production-ready](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/interoperability/archive/2013/04/22/redis-on-windows-stable-and-reliable.aspx), but they haven't exactly packaged it up neatly for installation on a server, especially if you want to run their [RedisWatcher](https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis/tree/2.6/msvs/RedisWatcher) service to keep an eye on it, which is recommended. (I tried building RedisWatcher myself per their instructions, but the required Wix Toolset managed to mess up my system pretty good. I won't go into it.) Fortunately they've provided all the binaries you need, just not all in one place. From the [README](https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis/blob/2.6/README.md):

> So far the RedisWatcher is not carried over to 2.6. However this
>   should not be affected by the Redis version, and the code in the 2.4
>   branch should work with the Redis 2.6 binaries.

So you'll need to download binaries from 2 branches in order to get all the necessary bits. Without further ado, here are the steps:

1. Download and extract the [Redis binaries from the 2.6 branch](https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis/raw/2.6/bin/release/redisbin64.zip)
2. Copy all extracted binaries to c:\redis\bin
3. Create another folder at c:\redis\inst1
4. Download and extract the [RedisWatcher binaries from the 2.4 branch](https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis/raw/2.4/msvs/bin/release/rediswatcherbin.zip)
5. Run InstallWatcher.msi. This should create a Windows service called Redis watcher.
6. Open up the Windows Services console and start the Redis watcher service.
7. (optional) RedisWatcher should have installed to C:\Program Files (x86)\RedisWatcher. There you'll find a config file called watcher.conf, which you can edit to set up additional instances, use different paths than I specified in steps 2 & 3, etc. You will not need to restart the service for changes to take effect.

Comment: You'll be happy to try this one. It works (on my Windows 2008 R2 64bit server at least). Takes you 5 minutes.

Comment: I receive a nice error when running InstallWatcher.msi:
There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A DLL required for this install to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor.

Comment: At the end, if you want to know that it's installed and working fine, you can download the Redis Desktop Manager (https://github.com/uglide/RedisDesktopManager or via Chocolatey). By default, the Host is localhost running on port 6379.

Comment: **Chocolatey** for install it : http://geekindulgence.com/install-redis-as-a-windows-service-using-chocolatey/ Useful for development machine IMHO. For server, I'm confused it.

Comment: redis 2.6.12 is the last version that works on Windows Server 2003.

Answer (score 170):

The most updated (only few minor releases behind) version of Redis can be found [here](https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis/releases). This repository provides you with 3.2.100 version (current is 3.2) whereas the [most upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10525215/1090562) gives you only 2.4.6 version and the last update to the repo was 2 years ago.

The installation is straightforward: just copy everything from the archive to any folder and run **redis-server.exe** to run the server and **redis-cli.exe** to connect to this server through the shell.

Comment: Straightforward if just want to run the exe, which I'd never do in a production environment without the watcher service, and they haven't provided binaries for that in the 2.6 branch for whatever reason. Fortunately the 2.4 version of the service is compatible with the 2.6 version of the exe - see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20200022/62600) to get it all up an running.

Comment: @ToddMenier most probably no one would run exe in production environment, because people would use some linux system for this. This is how to set up redis to be able to play with it and to learn (and I do not see why would I need to run multiple instances of redis here)

Comment: I'm running it in production and it works great. That said, all else being equal you are right, Linux is the way to go. But we're a small Windows shop without much *nix expertise to speak of.

Comment: +1 ( for the img trick) . ps - how can I make my windows run the redis server without user login ? is there any service version for redis server executable ? for example - there server was reset , and now the logon window appear. but I want redis server - at that point - to be running.

Comment: Thanks, Salvador.  This was just what I was looking for.  To show my gratitude,  I just gave you double credit.  One upvote for the correct answer, and one upvote for pointing me away from the outdated, yet most upvoted answer.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoftarchive/redis/releases/tag/win-3.2.100 download the msi installer and install and cd to the installed directory and typ 'ping' to test and thats it

Comment: I prefer this method myself. +1

Answer (score 125):

To install Redis for Windows

You can choose either from these sources

1. https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis/releases
   or
2. https://github.com/rgl/redis/downloads

*Personally I preferred the **first** option*

- Download [Redis-x64-2.8.2104.zip](https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis/releases/tag/win-2.8.2104)
- Extract the zip to prepared directory
- run `redis-server.exe` or `redis-server.exe --maxheap 2gb`

[image]

- then run `redis-cli.exe`

[image]

[image]

You can start using Redis now, please refer for [commands](http://redis.io/commands)

Comment: This worked for me (zip), i tried with the msi that is listed on the same link but didn't work.

Comment: Please note that you might get behavior that you click on "redis-server.exe" and nothing happens. Actually, you need to run that exe from command prompt and supply "--maxheap" param. Something like...

"redis-server --maxheap 1024M"

Comment: This is the definitive answer. Easiest most reliable way to get "official" redis on windows.  thx

Comment: Please note: just get the latest release. Happy coding!

Comment: Yep, for windows :)

Comment: I was wondering how this will translate to when we, for example, decide to host our application on a cloud? How will we instruct the cloud server to do these task, like starting `redis-server.exe`?

Comment: @AwshafIshtiaque this is just for local setup, there are a lot of options you can use redis in cloud,  you can use fully manage in memory service like  uptash redis vercel, elasticcache AWS,or host it to your nginx server for cloud. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorial_collections/how-to-install-and-secure-redis

Answer (score 62):

Maybe its a little Late but, **I was able to run Redis on Windows 10 Aniversary Update.**
Windows 10 Aniversary Update Comes with **Bash on Ubuntu on Windows**, simply, it comes with bash.
Below are the two tutorial that I followed: 
1- [How to Install and Use the Linux Bash Shell on Windows 10](https://www.howtogeek.com/249966/how-to-install-and-use-the-linux-bash-shell-on-windows-10/)
2- [How To Install and Use Redis](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-redis)
Below is the image of running Redis.
Enjoy :)
[image: Redis running on port 6379]

Comment: As a note, I installed Ubuntu 18 from the Windows store and had to `sudo apt install gcc make` before I could get Redis installed and built. Ran into this one as well ;) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37103054/redis-installation-fails-when-running-make-command

Comment: How do you access this install from windows?

Comment: you access it from Bash. and if you are running an application like Laravel you just need to setup the variables in environment file and redis will be available in your project. Because of its port 6379

Comment: I had tried the instruction in link 2, it did not work for me but this did: https://redislabs.com/blog/redis-on-windows-10/,  with ubuntu 18.04

Comment: This is the way to go (WSL), but the details are missing (are behind links). @Ogglas 's answer is the same but with the installation instructions.

Answer (score 57):

If you have `Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)`, natively on Windows 10 and Windows Server 2019 you can do it like this:

Set up WSL:

1. To enable Windows Subsystem for Linux, follow the instructions on
   [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10#install-the-windows-subsystem-for-linux). The short version is: In Windows 10, Microsoft
   replaces Command Prompt with PowerShell as the default shell. Open
   PowerShell as Administrator and run this command to enable Windows
   Subsystem for Linux (WSL):

   ```
   Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux
   ```
2. Reboot Windows after making the change—note that you only need to do this one time.
3. Download and install one of the supported Linux distros from the [Microsoft Store](http://microsoft.com/store). Ubuntu works fine.
   *Note that `Ubuntu 20.04 LTS` may give you some trouble because of a [known issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4898) with the realtime clock (as of August 2020). Choosing `Ubuntu 18.04 LTS` instead avoids that issue.*

Install and Test Redis:

1. Launch the installed distro from your Windows Store and then install redis-server. The following example works with Ubuntu (you’ll need to wait for initialization and create a login upon first use):

   ```
   > sudo apt-get update
   > sudo apt-get upgrade
   > sudo apt-get install redis-server
   > redis-cli -v
   ```
2. Restart the Redis server to make sure it is running:

   ```
   > sudo service redis-server restart
   ```
3. Execute a simple Redis command to verify your Redis server is
   running and available:

   ```
   $ redis-cli 
   127.0.0.1:6379> set user:1 "Oscar"
   127.0.0.1:6379> get user:1
   "Oscar"
   ```
4. To stop your Redis server:

   ```
   > sudo service redis-server stop
   ```

Source:

https://redislabs.com/blog/redis-on-windows-10/

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux

Comment: A note- the newest version for ubuntu in the store did not work for me. Had to uninstall and install the 18.04 version instead for redis to work.

Comment: This is the most up-to-date way to use Redis on Windows 10.

Comment: As per @JLI's comment above, there is a known issue with Ubuntu 20.04 in combination with WLS. Using 18.04 is easier than any of the fixes offered on the corresponding issue: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4898

Comment: I'm using Debian via WLS and it's working just fine

Comment: I'm using Win 10.0.18363.1198 + WSL 1 (confirmed using PS 'wsl -l -v') and Ubuntu 20.04 here without issues. Redis is running fine and receiving commands. This is not a production environment, but for dev+test all seems in order.

Comment: Should be accepted as the right answer. Just wanted to confirm what @TomDibble has said, I tried using Ubuntu 20.04. There's a bit moment of stuck when I ran `sudo apt-get upgrade`, but I pressed `CTRL + C` which I thought would abort the operation, but then it sets up the downloaded package. I thought I have to install Ubuntu 18.04, but I continue with the redis installation first. And well, the rest of the command **just works**. Will update if I finally have to change back to 18.04.

Comment: the most helpful post for this issue, thank you @Ogglas

Answer (score 53):

Go to the [releases](https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis/releases) and you can get a ZIP file containing the relevant files *as well as* a Word document called `RedisService.docx` with the following instructions:

> Installing the Service
>
> *--service-install*
>
> This must be the first argument on the redis-server command line. Arguments after this are passed in the order they occur to Redis when the service is launched. The service will be configured as Autostart and will be launched as "NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService". Upon successful installation a success message will be displayed and Redis will exit.
>   This command does not start the service.
>
> For instance:
>
> > redis-server --service-install redis.windows.conf --loglevel verbose

And then later, in the same document, another example:

> The following would install and start three separate instances of Redis as a service:
>
> > redis-server --service-install -–service-name redisService1 –port 10001
> >
> > redis-server --service-start --service-name redisService1
> >
> > redis-server --service-install --service-name redisService2 –port 10002
> >
> > redis-server --service-start --service-name redisService2
> >
> > redis-server --service-install --service-name redisService3 –port 10003
> >
> > redis-server --service-start --service-name redisService3

From what I can gather, this appears to be the new way forward rather than messing with a separate Windows service to monitor and restart the CLI.

Comment: Current release (redis-2.8.12.zip) only works for x64 Windows.
Try 2.6 branch for the x86 release, but this one doesn't run as a service: https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis/tree/2.6/bin/release

Comment: Is this method valid for 2.8?

Comment: Do we need to install Visual Studio, just for installing Redis on Windows? How stupid. :|

Comment: Binaries were moved to Releases page https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis/releases

Comment: Thanks, Igor! I've updated the introductory paragraph above to reflect that change.

Comment: Did this but the port command did not work, só I just tried:

  redis-server --service-install --service-name Redis

And it worked

Answer (score 37):

Download redis from 
[Download Redis for windows](https://github.com/rgl/redis/downloads)

- Then install it
- open cmd with admin rights
- run command `net start redis`

Thats it.

Comment: if you have not connected with redis For windows from Command Prompt, cd C:\Program Files\Redis and then redis-server

Answer (score 32):

MS Open Tech recently made a version of Redis available for download on Github.  They say that it isn't production ready yet, but keep an eye on it.

[Github repo](https://github.com/MSOpenTech/Redis)

[Download releases as MSIs](https://github.com/MicrosoftArchive/redis/releases)

Comment: https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis/tree/2.8.4_msopen/bin/release - There are some binaries now.

Comment: @arun I just checked and it works. Maybe there was a hiccup or github is blocked for you?

Comment: Hmm, I even logged in. Still doesn't work for me. But I am using Salvador Dali's solution now.

Comment: This answer is outdated havent been built new releases since 2016. latest recommendation is on windows10 to install under WSL

Comment: https://github.com/tporadowski/redis has carried on with updating MS Open Tech to the ~latest versions of redis

Answer (score 32):

You can use Memurai for Windows, a Redis-compatible cache and datastore for Windows, currently compatible with Redis 5. Memurai aims to fulfill the need for a supported Redis-compatible datastore on the Windows platform. At its core, it’s based on Redis source code, ported to run natively on Windows, and it’s designed to provide the level of reliability and performance required for production environments. Memurai is free for development and testing. You can learn more and download Memurai at https://www.memurai.com.

Alexis Campailla
CEO, Memurai

Comment: As much as I appreciate your efforts, that EULA is a no-no. Pass.

Comment: I think using this is the more up to date way to natively run Redis on Windows.

Comment: Is there an open source edition or a limited feature production edition available ?

Comment: @Tushar there is no open source or free production edition. However we have pricing plans that accommodate different (eg small startup) needs, so I recommend you reach out at https://www.memurai.com/contact

Answer (score 26):

## There are two ways. You can use MSI installation file or do it manually:

#### First download the msi or the zip file:

You can download both files from here:

https://github.com/MicrosoftArchive/redis/releases

#### Watch video tutorial (video covers example of both installations)

See this installation video tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ncFhlv-gBXQ

### Instruction - for those who can not YT at work:

You can download a moderately out-of-date precompiled version of Redis for 32-bit
and 64-bit Windows thanks to Dusan Majkic from his GitHub page: https://github.com/dmajkic/redis/downloads. Go ahead and do that now.

After you download Redis, you’ll need to extract the executables from the zip file.
As long as you’re using a version of Windows more recent than Windows XP, you
should be able to extract Redis without any additional software. Do that now.

After you’ve extracted either the 32- or 64-bit version of Redis to a location of your
choice (depending on your platform and preferences; remember that 64-bit Windows
can run 32- or 64-bit Redis, but 32-bit Windows can only run 32-bit Redis), you can
start Redis by double-clicking on the redis-server executable. After Redis has
started, you should see a window similar to figure A.1.

src: https://redis.com/ebook/appendix-a/a-3-installing-on-windows/a-3-2-installing-redis-on-window/

Comment: Man it would be nice if someone just wrote down what was in the video.  Not everyone can youtube at work.

Comment: In the downloaded zip archive, there is an instruction file in docx.
Its copy in txt is also here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MSOpenTech/redis/3.0/Windows%20Service%20Documentation.md on https://github.com/MicrosoftArchive/redis under the heading "How to configure and deploy Redis on Windows ".

Comment: @DevWL Microsoft archive doesn't support newer version of redis, but in this address (https://github.com/tporadowski/redis/releases ) exists up to version 5 .

Answer (score 23):

Since MSOpenTech's port of Redis is no longer maintained - anyone interested in **native port of Redis for Windows** can now get the version 4.0.14 and 5.0.10 from here: https://github.com/tporadowski/redis/releases.
This fork is a merge of latest 3.2.100 version from MSOpenTech and 4.0.14/5.0.10 from [antirez/redis](https://github.com/antirez/redis) with a couple of bugfixes.

Comment: Loved your solution

Answer (score 19):

I don't run redis on windows. There's too much hassle involved in keeping up with the ports, and they lag behind redis-stable by a version or two all the time.

Instead I run redis on a [Vagrant](http://vagrantup.com) virtual machine that runs redis for me. I've bundled up the whole thing into a simple github [repo](http://github.com/jasonpunyon/redishobo) so everyone can get in on the fun without too much hassle. The whole thing is an automated build so there's no mess. I blogged about the details [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20181222064919/http://jasonpunyon.com/blog/2013/01/28/get-your-redis-on-on-windows/).

Comment: How to you access Redis once the vm boots? by IP?

Comment: I think the port gets forwarded if I'm not mistaken

Comment: @StephenPatten: Yeah, you should be able to access it at `localhost:6379`.

Answer (score 16):

To install **Redis** on Windows system follow the below steps:

1. Visit one of the **below link:**

https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis/releases **(recommended)**
https://github.com/rgl/redis/downloads

2. Download **MSI file.**
3. Follow the **installation Wizard** and install the program on your system. *(do not change the installation path that is "C:\Program Files\Redis")*
4. Search for **"Edit system environment variable"** on your **start menu**
5. Click on **"Environment Variable" button**
6. Select **"Path"** and click on **"Edit"**
7. Now click on **"New"**
8. Paste **C:\Program Files\Redis** *(or the path in case you have changed while installing)*
9. Click on **"Okay", "Okay" and "Okay"**

Now open your **Terminal** (command prompt) and run `redis-cli`

Well I am getting some error to open `redis-server` (It was working fine till now but not sure what's wrong so figuring out and will update this answer)

Comment: I followed the same steps and it worked. Before renning the redis-cli make sure to run redis-server.

Comment: Both of those options are now very old and out of date versions of Redis. Getting the latest Docker version or using WSL are better options.

Comment: Why is this posted like a new answer when it repeats information in previous answers?

Answer (score 14):

I think these is the two most simple ways to run Redis on Windows

## 1 - Native (and updated) port for Windows

As described [here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/redis-windows#running-microsofts-native-port-of-redis) on *Option 3) Running Microsoft's native port of Redis*:

> 1. Download the redis-latest.zip native 64bit Windows port of redis
>
> `wget https://github.com/ServiceStack/redis-windows/raw/master/downloads/redis-latest.zip`
>
> 2. Extract redis64-latest.zip in any folder, e.g. in c:\redis
> 3. Run the redis-server.exe using the local configuration
>
> `cd c:\redis`
>
> `redis-server.exe redis.conf`
>
> 4. Run redis-cli.exe to connect to your redis instance
>
> `cd c:\redis`
>
> `redis-cli.exe`

## 2 - With Vagrant

You can use Redis on Windows with Vagrant, as described [here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/redis-windows):

> 1. Install Vagrant on Windows
> 2. Download the vagrant-redis.zip vagrant configuration
>
>    `wget https://raw.github.com/ServiceStack/redis-windows/master/downloads/vagrant-redis.zip`
> 3. Extract vagrant-redis.zip in any folder, e.g. in c:\vagrant-redis
> 4. Launch the Virtual Box VM with vagrant up:
>
>    `cd c:\vagrant-redis`
>
>    `vagrant up`
>
> This will launch a new Ubuntu VM instance inside Virtual Box that will
>   automatically install and start the latest stable version of redis.

Comment: Also at this site is a way to run Redis w/o vagrant. In windows 8 I had it running in 2 minutes.

Comment: This was helpful! Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

If you're happy with a bit of Powershell, you can also get very up-to-date Windows binaries using Powershell and chocolatey.

First, add chocolatey to Powershell following the instructions here (one simple command line as admin): https://chocolatey.org/

```
@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command "iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))" && SET PATH=%PATH%;%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\chocolatey\bin
```

Then, use Powershell to get the redis package from chocolatey: http://chocolatey.org/packages/redis-64

```
choco install redis-64
```

Redis will be installed in something like C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\redis-64.2.8.9

> Windows PowerShell Copyright (C) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All
>   rights reserved.
>
> PS C:\windows\system32> choco install redis-64 Chocolatey (v0.9.8.27)
>   is installing 'redis-64' and dependencies. By installing you accept
>   the license for 'redis-64' an d each dependency you are installing.
>
> redis-64 v2.8.9 Added
>   C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\redis-benchmark.exe shim pointed to
>   '..\lib\redis-64.2.8.9\redis-benchmark.exe'. Added
>   C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\redis-check-aof.exe shim pointed to
>   '..\lib\redis-64.2.8.9\redis-check-aof.exe'. Added
>   C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\redis-check-dump.exe shim pointed to
>   '..\lib\redis-64.2.8.9\redis-check-dump.exe'. Added
>   C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\redis-cli.exe shim pointed to
>   '..\lib\redis-64.2.8.9\redis-cli.exe'. Added
>   C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\redis-server.exe shim pointed to
>   '..\lib\redis-64.2.8.9\redis-server.exe'. Finished installing
>   'redis-64' and dependencies - if errors not shown in console, none
>   detected. Check log for errors if  unsure

Then run the server with

```
redis-server
```

Or the CLI with

```
redis-cli
```

Follow the instructions in C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\redis-64.2.8.9\RedisService.docx to install the redis service

Answer (score 9):

The [Redis download page](http://redis.io/download) now has links to some unofficial Windows ports. The dmajkic one seems to be the most popular/complete.

More detailed answer: [How to run Redis as a service under Windows](http://www.saltwebsites.com/2012/how-run-redis-service-under-windows)

Answer (score 9):

One of the most easy way to run Redis on windows host is to use Docker Redis container. Just fire up Hyper-V, Download Docker and run Redis

Answer (score 7):

I am using [Memurai](https://www.memurai.com/) which is Redis-compatible cache and datastore for Windows. It is also recommended by Microsoft open tech as it written on their former project [here](https://github.com/microsoftarchive/redis).

> This project is no longer being actively maintained. If you are
>   looking for a Windows version of Redis, you may want to check out
>   Memurai. Please note that Microsoft is not officially endorsing this
>   product in any way.

Answer (score 6):

you can install Redis by following this article:
https://github.com/ServiceStack/redis-windows
but for going straight, you can download it by this link:
https://github.com/ServiceStack/redis-windows/raw/master/downloads/redis-latest.zip
after downloading, go to the directory which you like to put your files,then extract the zip file, then open a command prompt and go to the directory where you extracted your file, then type "redis-server" and hit enter(for opening redis-cli open command and route to redis directory, but instead of "redis-server" execute "redis-cli").

Answer (score 5):

I've provided [installation instructions and downloads](https://github.com/msopentech/redis) for the 2 most popular ways of running Redis on windows at: https://github.com/mythz/redis-windows that shows how to:

1. Use [Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/) to run the latest stable version of Redis inside a
   VirtualBox VM.
2. Download and run [Microsoft's Native Windows port of Redis](https://github.com/msopentech/redis)

Comment: Once vagrant has got the box up and running, how do you access redis? I think the latest build did not compile redis correctly. This would be vagrant on windows 64bit

Comment: Humm, I see in the commands that are executed that the redis port was forwarded :) So I assume it means localhost:6379 is where I use redis from

Comment: Yeah, the redis build failed :(

Answer (score 5):

**Using Windows 10?**

`https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10`

**/etc/apt/sources.list**

```
(Debian 10 Buster/Bullseye)
Installs latest stable Redis (5.0.6 at time of posting)

deb https://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye main
deb https://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates main
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security/ buster/updates main
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian bullseye-backports main
```

```
apt install redis-server
```

Answer (score 5):

Today I know these 4 options:

The first is an open source fork that is on [tporadowski/redis](https://github.com/tporadowski/redis) that offers compatibility with version 5 (version 6 in development).

The second is [memurai](https://www.memurai.com/) (paid), compatible with version 5, has support and a free version for development.

The third is the [zkteco-home/redis-windows](https://github.com/zkteco-home/redis-windows) recently, which offers compatibility with version 7, but is not open source.

There is also the option to run via WSL. But I don't recommend it in production environments.

Answer (score 4):

You can go through the below steps and get setup redis in windows.

1. Download the Redis zip file.  Click [here](https://redis.io/download)!
2. Extract the zip file to the prepared directory.
3. Run redis-server.exe, you can either directly run redis-server.exe by clicking or run via command prompt.

[image]

4. Run redis-cli.exe, after successfully running the redis-server. You can access it and test commands by running redis-cli.exe Test
   PING command is used to test if a connection is still alive.

[image]

Comment: exe not in v6.0.9

Comment: Did you mean to download it from here: https://github.com/tporadowski/redis ? This answer works without WSL.

Answer (score 3):

You can try out [baboonstack](http://www.litixsoft.de/english/baboonstack/#packageredisio), which includes redis and also a node.js and mongoDB version manager. And it's cross platform.

Answer (score 3):

The redis version on windows was published by microsoft open tech team But recently this project has been archived to https://github.com/MicrosoftArchive/redis read-only and will not update. Has stopped development

Answer (score 3):

Here are my steps to install Redis 4.0.8 on Windows 10 Pro (1709) via Windows  Subsystem for Linux:

```
in home/user/
   01 wget http://download.redis.io/releases/redis-4.0.8.tar.gz
   02 tar xzf redis-4.0.8.tar.gz
   03 cd redis-4.0.8/
   04 sudo apt-get install make
   05 sudo apt-get update
   06 sudo apt-get install gcc
   07 cd deps
   08 make hiredis jemalloc linenoise lua geohash-int
   09 cd ..
   10 make
```

You can skip several steps if you have an up-to-date environment.

Comment: how do you create a service with it? some of us are not experienced in these areas

Comment: Running as a service/server: $ src/redis-server --from the site: https://redis.io/download

Comment: Eh? "here are my instructions to install redis on windows" ... bunch of linux commands run in linux using "Windows Subsystem" ... :facepalm:

Comment: War - this is using Window but via Windows Subsystem for Linux --I find this to be the best solution.

Comment: Persistant services under WSL is not supported. Its a downer to run `sudo service redis-server start` everytime the win10 box is restarted. better to use a docker container

Answer (score 3):

The MSOpenTech-Redis project is no longer being actively maintained. If you are looking for a Windows version of Redis, you may want to check out Memurai. Please note that Microsoft is not officially endorsing this product in any way. More details in https://github.com/microsoftarchive/redis

To install & setup Redis Server on Windows 10 https://redislabs.com/blog/redis-on-windows-10

To install & setup Redis Server on macOS & Linux https://redis.io/download

Also, you may install & setup Redis Server on Linux via the package manager

For quick Redis Server Installation & Setup Guide for macOS https://github.com/rahamath18/Redis-on-MacOS

Answer (score 2):

Reading about some users running Redis in a VM, it brought to my mind the recommendations from Redis team :

Redis runs slower on a VM. Virtualization toll is quite high because for many common operations. (...) Prefer to run Redis on a physical box, especially if you favor deterministic latencies. On a state-of-the-art hypervisor (VMWare), result of redis-benchmark on a VM through the physical network is almost divided by 2 compared to the physical machine, with some significant CPU time spent in system and interruptions.

Answer (score 2):

The Redis project does not officially support Windows. However, the Microsoft Open Tech group develops and maintains this Windows port targeting Win64.

http://redis.io/download

Answer (score 2):

There is no native version of the Redis for windows.(Only some old versions are available)

But you can install latest versions using WSL(Windows Subsystem for Linux), Refer the following blog from the Redis Labs:

https://redislabs.com/blog/redis-on-windows-10

Answer (score 2):

after you downloaded and installed Redis, checkout the documentation doc in the Redis installation folder. you can find everything there in regard to how to start and stop redis-server. 
If you installed Redis through the .exe file chances are you're already running it. to make sure whether the Redis server is running checkout the Task Manager -> services tab.

[image]

under status field you can see whether it's running or not. If it's stopped right click on it and start the service.

[image]

You can write Redis commands in redis-cli, and to open redis-cli in terminal type:

```
C:\Program Files\Redis\redis-cli.exe
```

for ease of access you can add the Redis installation directory as an environment variable.

Answer (score 2):

You can install Redis on Windows 10 using Windows Subsystem for Linux(a.k.a WSL2). WSL2 is a compatibility layer for running Linux binary executables natively on Windows 10 and Windows Server 2019. WSL2 lets developers run a GNU/Linux environment(that includes command-line tools, utilities, and applications) directly on Windows.

Follow the link below to create Redis database on Microsoft Windows 10 https://developer.redislabs.com/create/windows

Answer (score 1):

Latest Redis x86 builds (32-bit) can be found here:
http://bitsandpieces.it/redis-x86-32bit-builds-for-windows

Says that he will maintain both 2.8.* and 3.0.* branches.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from: http://avenshteinohad.blogspot.com/2016/01/redis-jedis-quickstart.html

> If you use windows, use MSOpenTech version from:
>
> https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis

You also might find this post useful to get started with basic commands.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

**Installing Redis**

Windows

⚫ **Windows 8.1 and Earlier**

1. Download Redis (msi) from the link
   https://github.com/MicrosoftArchive/redis/releases
2. Run the installer
3. Open the folder where Redis has been installed and Start redis-server to check if redis is working by clicking on redis-server
4. Stop Redis server by typing SHUTDOWN SAVE or force quit by CTRL + C
5. Open Start
6. Type Environment Variables and click on edit environment variables and path
7. Inside System variables, click on path
8. In the next window click on new.
9. Add a new path
10. `C:\Program Files\{Your Redis Version}`
    Where Redis Version is the Redis version installed on your system For e.g. C:\Program Files\Redis-x64-3.2.100
11. Verify That Setup was Successful Check by typing redis-cli or redis-server

⚫ **Windows 10**

1. Step Up WSL

a. Run Windows Powershell as Administrator

b. Run the following command

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux
```

c. Reboot Windows after making the change

d. Download Ubuntu Distros from windows store from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/ubuntu-1804/9n9tngvndl3q?activetab=pivot%3Aoverviewtab

2. Install and Test Redis

a. Launch the downloaded distro and run the following commands

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install redis-server
redis-cli -v
```

Note: Incase of any errors with installation, refer this [article](https://www.how2shout.com/how-to/solve-wslregisterdistribution-failed-with-error-0x800701bc.html).

Comment: Redis from MicrosoftArchive is old, unsopported and full of bugs. I would not recommend it for any use.

Running Redis with WSL is not recommended for production use last time I checked.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is the easiest way to get the latest version of Redis - use NuGet Manager:

1) Open NuGet setup [page](http://docs.nuget.org/consume/installing-nuget)  and download Command-Line Utility
(The latest version of the nuget.exe command-line tool is always available from https://nuget.org/nuget.exe)

2) Copy this file to somewhere (for example, `C:\Downloads`)

3) Start a command prompt as an Administrator and execute follow commands:

```
cd C:\Downloads
nuget.exe install redis-64
```

4) In the `Downloads` folder will be the latest version of Redis (`C:\Downloads\Redis-64.2.8.19` in my case)

5) Run `redis-server.exe` and start working

P.S. Note: redis from [Download Redis for windows](http://docs.nuget.org/consume/installing-nuget) contains a very old version of Redis: 2.4.6

Comment: If you try it today, you get the error `Unable to find package 'redis-64'.`

Answer (score 0):

i updated the way you can compile and run redis 5 on windows 10 using cygwin
https://github.com/meiry/redis5_compiled_for_windows10

Comment: cygwin handles registry changes poorly. msys2 is a better method of compiling redis.

Comment: @TamusJRoyce hi! how would one compile redis on msys2?

Comment: https://github.com/redis/redis - follow the steps in the readme. Make sure when you install msys2 and mingw, you include the dependencies in the msys2 installer. Recently, also I highly recommend wsl (I like wsl 1 over 2, as 1 uses windows kernel without cpu virtualization & this app is in-memory - disk is slower in wsl1, but either works). Using Ubuntu on Windows. Works great for me in wsl1 ubuntu using apt-get and .bash-rc startup!

Answer (score -2):

[image][image][image]

```
VARY EASY:(NO ANY CAMMAN OR NOT GOING TO ANY LINK,ONLY FOLLOW THIS STEP ,FOR ALL VERSION)   
             FIRST INSTALL REDIS 
                -->>AFTER OPEN TASKBAR
                -->>OPEN SERVICE(taskbar service)
                -->>CHOOSE REDIS 
                -->>RIGTH CLICK ON REDIS SERVICE AND OPEN SERVICE(VIEW IMAGES) 
                -->>CLICK ON START OR RESTART.(ALSO SET AUTOSTART)
```