# Redis service is not run automatically

Tags: redis, windows-server-2012

I installed redis service on Windows Server 2012. It is in task manager but it stopped & I can't run it.
It works if I start redis-server.exe file manually. 
What I can do to make it work automatically?

Comment: Here's your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10525215/290343

Comment: @OferZelig yes, if you want a Redis port that is 3 years behind.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify which Windows port of Redis your are running (there is no official one), but [MSOpenTech's](https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis) is by far the most current, and the corresponding [RedisWatcher](https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis/tree/2.6/msvs/RedisWatcher) service will keep it up and running. From the RedisWatcher readme:

> RedisWatcher is an application that will run one or more instances of
>   redis-server. If the redis-server process terminates, then
>   RedisWatcher will restart it.
>
> RedisWatcher is installed as a Windows service. It can also run as an
>   application by passing 'console' as a command line argument.

For whatever reason, they have not provided binaries for the watcher service in the latest (2.6) branch, but the 2.4 version of the service is compatible, and they have binaries for that. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20200022/62600) for detailed instructions on getting it all up and running.