# Which is the "official" Redis port for Windows?

Tags: windows, redis

I'm a little confused about which Redis port is the "official" Windows port. I know that there is no truly official Windows port, as there is none on Redis.io. However, I have discovered two different Windows ports:

- https://github.com/MSOpenTech/Redis -- the MSOpenTech version
- https://github.com/rgl/redis/downloads -- the Dušan Majkić port that MSOpenTech credits

Does anybody know which one is preferred? I know everyone says there is no stable Redis port for Windows, but I'm running the Dušan Majkić version, and it runs like a dream.

Comment: As noted, MSOpenTech's is by far the most current port, years ahead of all others at this point. See [my answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20200022/62600) for detailed steps on how to get it up and running - it's not particularly straightforward.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MSOpenTech's port is enough good (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/interoperability/archive/2013/04/22/redis-on-windows-stable-and-reliable.aspx)

Dušan Majkić's port has more downloads then MSOpenTech's port (comparing between github download page and nuget version of MSOpenTech), but it is no longer update and support only up to redis 2.4.6.

The benchmark of MSOpenTech's port shows same as linux version, and Dušan Majkić's port bechmark is approximately 1/3. (comparing between version 2.6.x of both MSOpenTech's port and linux version with 2.4.6 of Dušan Majkić's port so the results of benchmark may not fair, but we care only the best).

And the last, we're using MSOpenTech's port in a live product with no errors :)

Comment: It does seem to run well, but is there an easy way to wrap it in a Windows service like the Dusan Majkic version? It's written in C++, apparently, and I'm a C# guy. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, we can use https://github.com/kcherenkov/redis-windows-service to host MSOpenTech port as a windows service.

Comment: See RedisService.docx in the bin/release folder. Installing the Service
--service-install
This must be the first argument on the redis-server command line. Arguments after this are passed in the order they occur to Redis when the service is launched. The service will be configured as Autostart and will be launched as "NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService". Upon successful installation a success message will be displayed and Redis will exit.
This command does not start the service.
For instance:
redis-server --service-install redis.window.conf --loglevel verbose

Comment: The Windows installer downloaded here: http://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis/releases. will install the MSOpenTech Redis as an Windows service directly.

Comment: Looks like Microsoft will no longer support Redis for Windows. They archived it.

Comment: @Gokulnath Yes, I went this instead: https://github.com/ServiceStack/redis-windows

Answer (score 5):

Since other people end up here (like I did), I want to mention that above mentioned repo is abandoned but that's ok, on Windows 10, the way to do this using the [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) and then run Redis in a bash prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft OpenTech Redis has been abandoned in 2016.
In their last commit ([link](https://github.com/microsoftarchive/redis/commit/54e8c24657f4bab22f24356bd097706193727f4f)) they point to Memurai.