# Does Booksleeve work with a windows Redis (Redis installed as a Windows Service)?

Tags: windows, windows-services, redis, booksleeve

Does Booksleeve work with a windows Redis (Redis installed as a Windows Service) ?

I Installed [Redis as a Windows Service](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10525215) and I wanted to know if it was possible to use BookSleeve with it? Or is BookSleeve exclusively for a Redis installed on a Unix system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redis listens the same way whether it runs as a service or process.  Booksleeve connects the same way and shouldn't know the difference.

If this is a new project, you may want to consider looking into StackExchange.Redis.  It has succeeded Booksleeve and has the same people working on it.  Typically you will want to pick the more active project and StackExchange.Redis is used here on StackOverflow.

https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis

Answer (score 3):

It won't care, or even be aware of that fact. the protocol is the same either way, and it should work just fine.

Note also that there is now a supported MS fork, which can be easily installed via chocolatey or nuget via the name "Redis-64".