# CodeIgniter store PHP session in Redis

Tags: php, codeigniter, redis

I'm following [an article](http://simplapi.wordpress.com/2012/04/13/php-and-node-js-session-share-redi/) to save PHP sessions in Redis rather than the filesystem (so I can share session with node.js)

I understand how [session_set_save_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php) works but i'm confused on how to set it up with the CodeIgniter framework? Should I extend the CI_Session class and put the session_set_save_handler in there?

Comment: CI is a little strange , it doesn't use native php sessions http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html Might want to create a native session library and include it in controllers

Answer (score 1):

Redis session is supported in **Codeigniter version 3**

Open and Edit

> application/config/config.php

To enable Redis set session driver to "redis"

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'redis';
```

Example  of redis server path

> redis://hostname:port or tcp://hostname:port

Set the value of sess_save_path localhost for local testing

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'tcp://localhost:6379';
```

To test Redis on your localhost.

Please refer to my answer on [how to install Redis for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33931115/2314592)

Answer (score 0):

Store your session in database. 
In order to store sessions, you must first create a database table for this purpose. Here is the basic prototype (for MySQL) required by the session class:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `ci_sessions` (
    session_id varchar(40) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    ip_address varchar(45) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    user_agent varchar(120) NOT NULL,
    last_activity int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    user_data text NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (session_id),
    KEY `last_activity_idx` (`last_activity`)
);
```

SET

```
$config['sess_use_database'] = TRUE;
```

in `config.php` FILE.

Once enabled, the Session class will store session data in the DB.

Make sure you've specified the table name in your config file as well:

```
$config['sess_table_name'] = 'ci_sessions';
```