# Any Redis like DB that can be used on both Windows and Mac OS?

Tags: windows, node.js, macos, redis

We are a group developing a web application backend using Node.js, and we found RedisDB is really very helpful because of its sortedList, hash tables and so on.

But our problem is that Redis DB is not officially supported on Windows System. Our group members who are using the Windows system have trouble trying to install it. Could someone give a hand to show us how could we get round this problem? Or is there any other Redis like DB that can be used on both Windows and Mac OS?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily find the answer searching a bit (google, stackoverflow, ...)

[Redis on Windows](https://github.com/ServiceStack/redis-windows)

[On StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476945/how-do-i-run-redis-on-windows)

[On MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/interoperability/archive/2013/04/22/redis-on-windows-stable-and-reliable.aspx)