# Where can i get redis installation for window?

Tags: redis

I searched online and I found a very outdated redis-windows version https://github.com/rgl/redis/downloads from a stackoverflow answer [How do I run Redis on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476945/how-do-i-run-redis-on-windows)

Can anyone point me to where can I download the latest version of redis for windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis/releases has 2.8.19.1 redis installation for Windows (64-bit) released 17 days ago.

Sources of windows port are here: https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis

Answer (score 0):

Right here: https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis/releases. You can get unsigned binaries there, or, as the readme states, you can get signed binaries using Nuget or Chocolatey.

Comment: Links may go away in the future. Please select the useful sections of the link here so that the answer may always be there.

Answer (score 0):

The MSOpenTech site is the right source for the Windows port. You should also consider what Redis client you want to use. The two best ones are:

[StackExchange Redis Client](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis)

and

[ServiceStack Redis Client](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis)

I've used the ServiceStack Client extensively, but I've heard very good things about the StackExchange Client.

Answer (score 0):

Redis Installation Link for Windows

https://github.com/tporadowski/redis/releases

Comment: What are your reasons for recommending this link-only answer over the others. Now that the formatting does not make it stand out anymore? Any technical reason?

Answer (score 0):

A good alternative (if you don't want to install it directly on windows), is to enable and install WSL and then install redis from there as if you would install it on ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Memurai](https://www.memurai.com/). They have ported Redis to Windows, enhanced it for performance and to run natively on windows, developed Windows installers and provide professional support.