# PHP worker (Multiple processes and/or threads)

Tags: php, multithreading, pthreads, php-7

I'm trying to fetch statistical data from a web service. Each request has a response time of 1-2 seconds and I've to submit the request for thousands of IDs, one at a time. All requests would sum up to a few hours, because of the server's response time.

I want to parallelize as much requests as possible (the server's can handle it). I've installed PHP7 and pthreads (CLI-only), but the maximum number of threads is limited (20 in Windows PHP CLI), so I've to start multiple processes.

Is there any simple PHP based framework/library for multi-process/pthread and job-queue handling? I don't need a large framework like symfony or laravel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Workers

You could look into using [php-resque](https://github.com/chrisboulton/php-resque) which doesn't require pthreads.

You will have to run a local Redis server though (could also be remote). I believe you can run Redis on Windows, according to [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476945/how-do-i-run-redis-on-windows/30980729#30980729)

---

## Concurrent Requests

You may also want to look into sending concurrent requests using something like [GuzzleHttp](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle), you can find examples on how to use that [here](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#concurrent-requests)

#### From the Docs:

You can send multiple requests concurrently using promises and asynchronous requests.

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Promise;

$client = new Client(['base_uri' => 'http://httpbin.org/']);

// Initiate each request but do not block
$promises = [
    'image' => $client->getAsync('/image'),
    'png'   => $client->getAsync('/image/png'),
    'jpeg'  => $client->getAsync('/image/jpeg'),
    'webp'  => $client->getAsync('/image/webp')
];

// Wait on all of the requests to complete. Throws a ConnectException
// if any of the requests fail
$results = Promise\unwrap($promises);

// Wait for the requests to complete, even if some of them fail
$results = Promise\settle($promises)->wait();

// You can access each result using the key provided to the unwrap
// function.
echo $results['image']->getHeader('Content-Length');
echo $results['png']->getHeader('Content-Length');
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, php-resque looks nice!