# CredisException Error: Apache Bigcommerce Hello World

Tags: apache, composer-php, bigcommerce

I am trying to run the [BigCommerce Hello World](https://github.com/bigcommerce/hello-world-app-php-silex) app on Apache. It installs ok, but when I launch it, I get an error.

CredisException in Client.php line 447:
Connection to Redis failed after 1 failures.Last Error : (10061) No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

I tried disabling the Windows Firewall and that did not help.

I looked at Client.php line 447, but it is only the code to display the error message.

I have searched for a solution for 10+ hours and I cannot solve this issue.

Comment: It looks like that your problem is not connected to the BigCommerce example app. It doesn't deal with Redis at all. Check other code, it's not enough information to say more.

Comment: The error message points to 'Client.php' which is located at 'hello-world-app-php-silex/vendor/colinmollenhour/credis/Client.php'. This is a Composer dependency that is part of the app.

Comment: I don't see `colinmollenhour/credis` in the requirements. Please, run `composer why colinmollenhour/credis` and check which package requires it.

Comment: "require": { "colinmollenhour/credis": "~1.2", } is in composer.json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an error due to Redis, a key-value database store that this app uses in its example. Specifically because your program is unable to connect to it (most likely on port 6379, its default port).

I believe you would actually need to install and run Redis first on your machine for this app to work, before you can connect to it via Credis, a php Redis client (i.e. a PHP based program that allows you to connect to your Redis database).

Similarly, you wouldn't be able to use a MySQL client if MySQL was not installed on your machine.

Here are instructions on installing and running Redis on a Windows machine:

### [How do I run Redis on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476945/how-do-i-run-redis-on-windows)

Be sure to use the default port of 6379.

Comment: This worked!!! I manually installed Redis from [GitHub - MSOpen/redis](https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis/releases).