# Launch of Redis server on windows. The window closes itself

Tags: windows, redis

I am trying to run the Redis server on Windows. It seems to me that it performs all the steps according to the suggestions in this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476945/how-do-i-run-redis-on-windows/20200022#20200022).

But I do not see this window:

[image]

In my situation, after running the file redis-server.exe it closes automatically in about one second.

However, the redis-cli.exe file works correctly and displays itself correctly.

[image]

How can I solve this problem and run a Redis server?

Comment: Surely there is already a redis-server instance running, maybe on the background or as a windows service. So the second instance you try to run will fail trying to open sockets and will close.

Comment: How to solve the problem, then? quit currently working in the background? Can I somehow run two?

Comment: You can run multiple instances but they must run on different ports. You can specify the listening port via command-line, i.e. `start redis-server.exe --port 7777`

Answer (score 17):

Open **Task manager** > click **Details** tab and scroll till you find "**redis-server.exe**".
Right click on "**redis-server.exe**" and click "**End Process**".
Try again it should work now.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the exact same problem. I noticed that there is another 'hidden' running redis server because I was able to use the redis-cli to get info about it. I was using redis desktop manager before, so I uninstalled it and restarted my PC, an now it is working like a charm.
Also something else that I had a running redis docker container. So check your docker environment first.