# How to install Redis on Windows 10 pc

Tags: windows, redis, installation, jedis

I am currently experimenting with Minecraft servers on a Windows 10 machine. I wish to use Redis/Jedis to communicate between bungee cord servers. The download at redis.io/downloads is a compressed folder. How do I install without an exe or similar. I also have checked and I can't find an exe in the folders after uncompressed. Can you even run Redis on Windows? Anyway,

Thanks for the help,
Ed

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I run Redis on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476945/how-do-i-run-redis-on-windows)

Comment: Yes thank you. That's great! Have a good one.

Comment: I suggest you also take a look at Memurai: a production grade Redis-compatible cache for Windows.<br/>
More info about Memurai at https://www.memurai.com.