# Redis server not starting on windows 10

Tags: django, redis

I have to use redis so that in django i can have channels_redis. Problem is, the server doesnt run. Im not sure why, im new to this.

when i use this command:

```
>redis-server redis.windows.conf
[11428] 09 Aug 11:51:03.037 # Creating Server TCP listening socket 127.0.0.1:6379: bind: No error
```

then i use this:

```
>redis-server
[8524] 09 Aug 11:55:25.736 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
[8524] 09 Aug 11:55:25.741 # Creating Server TCP listening socket *:6379: bind: No such file or directory
```

As you can see these lines turn up and i dont know what to do. This is my folder:

[image]

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you read  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476945/how-do-i-run-redis-on-a) ?

Comment: @IdrisStack I tried todd meiner's answer. I ran InstallWatcher.msi but it didnt notify me in any way that the app has been installed, it just disappeared.  Do you happen to know the command for his sixth instruction?

Comment: @IdrisStack aight so i tried a lot of the other options, followed this tutorial as well https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ncFhlv-gBXQ , either the same issue or they are not doing anything. Is it because they are outdated or what

Comment: You can also try installing Redis in WSL(The Ubuntu sub system of Windows 10)

Comment: @AwesomeHunter dont think my pc can handle it but i will look into it. Thanks

Comment: It's quite easy, just a few clicks.  With it, installing redis-server is just a apt-install command. https://www.windowscentral.com/install-windows-subsystem-linux-windows-10